# Is there any way to put both string and array in single HashMap?

Tags: java

i'm moving from php to Java. and i'm trying to achieve something like below in Java :

```
$user = array(
            "firstname" => "myname",
            "lastname" => "surname",
            "phone" => array(
                        "home" => "123213213213",
                        "office" => "312321321312312",
                        "mobile" => "4532134213131312"
                       )
       )
```

is there any way to do like that in java?

Thanks!

Comment: That's possible, and what is the purpose? The example you shown works better with record that describes person with defined fields to store firstname, lastname and a collection of objects that decribe phone (number + type).

Comment: It's possible, but usually a terrible idea.  You're better off writing actual classes with strongly typed fields.

Comment: was just trying to get data from xml and set it in multidimensional array. so i can convert to sting and save or get easily form db later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are are few ways to make it closer, but nothing as convenient as that.

**Example 1:**

```
Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("firstname", "myname");
                put("lastname", "surname");
                put("phone", new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("home", "123213213213");
                        put("office", "312321321312312");
                        put("mobile", "4532134213131312");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Update example:

```
((Map)user.get("phone")).put("mobile2", "123");
```

Adding another map:

```
user.put("address", new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

(could perhaps be improved by use of putIfAbsent method, or the merge-methods)

Printing current contents:

```
System.out.println(user);
```

Gives:

```
{firstname=myname, address={}, phone={mobile2=123, mobile=4532134213131312, office=312321321312312, home=123213213213}, lastname=surname}
```

Comment: lets say i want to push "mobile2" into  "phone". how can i do that? 
thanks!

Comment: ((Map<String, Object>)user.get("phone")).put("mobile2", "123")

Comment: i tried to add another hashmap and value dynamicly. but got "java.lang.NullPointerException"

user.put("address", new HashMap<String, Object>()) . is this a wrong way?

Comment: Then you haven't initialized the user variable. Works for me. I'll update example above with output from printing contents after doing just that.

Comment: one more question. is it possinle to push it into db as sting and convert back to hashmap after pulling back form db? or any other way to do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JSON API in Java to create an object in the format you like. Here is the documentation of the JSON API

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Example:

```
String stringToParse = "{" + 
    "firstname: \"myname\"," +
    "lastname: \"surname\"," +
    "phone: [ " + 
        " { home: \"123213213213\" }, " +
        " { office: \"312321321312312\" }," +
        " { mobile: \"4532134213131312\" }" +
    "]" +
"}";

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance you can use the following code :

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("firstname", "myname");

    Map<String, String> phones = new HashMap<>();
    phones.put("home" , "123213213213");
    phones.put("office" , "312321321312312");
    phones.put("mobile" , "4532134213131312");
    map.put("phones", phones);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is "possible" but I don't think it would be good convention (unless there is another way I am unaware of). I believe that this would work:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I would think that you would have to use a List object type instead of a array data type for a HashMap. If I were doing this, I would likely create my own class that handles this situation.